# MySQL Replication - Used to work, now get error 2026

Tags: mysql-5.5

I've had replication running now for about 2 years, with 1 master and 2 slaves. Both are through an SSL connection. I'm using MySQL 5.5.15 on the master (CentOS), and MySQL 5.14.46 on the slaves (on a Windows machine - don't ask).

Last week both slaves stopped replicating off the master, giving me an error code of 2026 and saying that they can't connect to the master. Looking in the error logs, both stopped being able to connect to the server at the same time - 16:46 in the afternoon.

I was here, I'm the only system admin and I was fiddling with anything on the server. In fact, it has run smoothly now for a long time. The SSL certificates appear to still be set up correctly in the master.

Has anybody else had a problem like this?

Comment: Are the certificates expired? `openssl x509 -in mycert.pem -dates -noout`